# How to include Ionic.io services in Ionic 2 beta

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

[ionic.io](https://ionic.io/) provides services like User Authentication, Push etc. Using Ionic services with ionic 1 seems to be well documented but for ionic 2 there is no documentation about it anywhere. I am impelementing an app using typescript, so what Should I import? I've already run

```
$ ionic add ionic-platform-web-client
```

But I am not able to find whay"t modules should I import to use user authentication module of Ionic.io It doesnt have any documentation(for angular2 or ionic2). Has anyone tried this yet? Can someone please guide me on this? I am not asking code snippets but just help on what to import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay Ionic finally released the notes for Ionic-V2,I can see the alert to the link from the V1 Docs site since yesterday.
This is the link [ionic.io v2 docs](http://docs.ionic.io/v2.0.0-beta)